# How do i get a list of all the files from a certain directory whos name contains a letters that i supply?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command

I want to create a command that will give me a list of files from a certain directory based on the pattern of letters i give it. Below is the code that i have at the moment but it for it to work i have to enter the correct filename. And for the output it shows me the full path to the file. Below $1 is the argument (pattern to search for).

find /path/to/directory -name $1 -type f

How would i do it so that all files matching the pattern are displayed and only the file name is displayed (rather than the path to the file).

Comment: `cd /path/to/directory; echo *[letters]*`

Comment: You probably just need to quote the parameter: `find ... -name "$1"` -- it will also probably need to be quoted when you invoke the script: `myscript.sh "*[abcd]*"`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps add the following besides the doublequotes around $1. Something like this in your script

```
find . -name "$1" -type f -exec basename {} \;
```